# How to add domain user to a group ( docker-users) in Windows 10 Enterprise? Unable to start Docker Windows Desktop

Tags: docker, windows-10, usergroups

I'm unable to add my username under docker-users group. Since I'm **not** a local user. My username **not listing** in Computer Management Users.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I ran the following command. User added to the docker-users group. I'm able to run docker-ce after the restart.

`net localgroup docker-users myusername /ADD`

Comment: Note that if you're using a network account `myusername` should be of the form `domain\user`.

Answer (score 1):

Docker can be run on windows 10 home through wsl 2.

Unfortunately, computer management doesn't allow you to manage user groups in windows 10 home.

To get around this, add your user to the docker-users group with the following command on the command line:

```
net localgroup "docker-users" "<your username>" /add
```

Once you receive a successful message, logout of your windows then log back on to activate:

To sign out of Windows 11, select `Start`. Select the Accounts icon (or picture), then select `Sign out`.

[image: screenshot]